# Kotlin: this expression in nested unnamed functions

Tags: kotlin

The Kotlin documentation describes how to access [*this* expressions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html) in nested classes.

Is it possible to access *this* expressions in nested unnamed functions? e.g:

```
str = "abcde"
str.run {                                                                                                                                                                                              
this.substring(0..2).run {                                                                                                                                                                         
    println("${this} is a substring of ${???}")                                                                                                                                                    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for the sake of answering the question as asked, for situations where this can improve readability, you can [use a label](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html):

```
str.run outer@ { // Define a label
    this.substring(0..2).run {
        println("${this} is a substring of ${this@outer}") // Use the label
    }
}
```

Oftentimes, you'll have implicit labels to use. For example, if the outer call is changed to use a different function name from the inner call, you can access it:

```
with (str) {
    this.substring(0..2).run {
        println("${this} is a substring of ${this@with}") // Use the implicit label
    }
}
```